# How to put together and provide a similar-case-based order to three datasets using dplyr library?

Tags: r, sorting, join, merge

I have three datasets I'm working:

**DATASET 1**

```
   structure(list(var_1 = c(1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 
16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 30, 44, 46, 49), var_2 = c("soap", 
"soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", 
"soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", 
"soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap"
), var_3 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A"), var_4 = c(988.368784828308, 999.685844324618, 999.786378084971, 
997.168905747014, 1004.23849942428, 1009.57481668809, 993.869639239065, 
1000.52851758583, 992.264115311031, 1001.27327945355, 998.166892731571, 
1004.37524298634, 1000.04055175821, 994.265544900897, 1002.95352732001, 
996.532966535325, 992.729713341507, 1002.65765002365, 1001.85698518142, 
992.952173664209, 1004.56661945183, 993.89476037793, 997.387419796121, 
995.368375334554, 995.772803883237), var_5 = c(994.834756009939, 
1002.23100741241, 998.699806256246, 1002.19344184533, 1002.44958531768, 
1013.71182331817, 995.867593313022, 1005.42592103256, 997.593221945247, 
1003.48359241788, 1001.48755216348, 1003.89476490635, 1001.94134174168, 
997.238535900595, 1001.74783962328, 996.684422052467, 991.843306038854, 
1000.90630208122, 1004.03366573065, 995.319451176897, 1004.9659437387, 
994.385347063973, 999.967477941096, 998.345285530291, 998.577182214779
), var_6 = c(1011.88022669726, 1015.09810043606, 1003.13771453335, 
1013.67789244066, 1007.47946451329, 1023.4166601996, 1006.2675210718, 
1012.99980379135, 1015.78997960857, 1009.93797956768, 1005.16656503461, 
1010.01354869538, 1008.64382513729, 1004.35678644331, 1004.93825547529, 
1006.54487921689, 999.143576420206, 1005.66176837543, 1006.59026080217, 
1001.63892755704, 1010.70319073912, 1006.04891324235, 1014.4393884283, 
1007.11820954752, 1009.1547320269), var_7 = c(988.221495702721, 
995.984841639886, 1004.4672957051, 999.116379988893, 1001.14544537612, 
1013.29862597967, 1000.02290694207, 1001.8997238369, 991.917076181167, 
1001.75469999858, 1002.55445787016, 1002.6131633385, 1000.1486358877, 
992.174732415707, 1002.3675247675, 995.463461260932, 1000.49899512487, 
1000.90194838628, 1000.15589773267, 998.838174280258, 1004.3385479368, 
993.730433866373, 999.111706290616, 997.041879724825, 995.587091814466
), var_8 = c(994.035709684742, 998.564426335124, 1003.52155765272, 
1005.49897156208, 999.56563615154, 1017.2093269366, 1004.9525336386, 
1006.12944883686, 998.758028059129, 1004.22150266269, 1004.19096721582, 
1002.0809544, 1003.05879540678, 997.228449343895, 1002.24515223348, 
997.990314049709, 1000.58839907176, 999.661325019717, 1002.55036185373, 
1001.6009125159, 1004.84522882347, 995.404874329182, 1003.15655538249, 
999.960896943128, 998.265161196589), var_9 = c(1008.23981597718, 
1005.06332653216, 1007.56089165218, 1013.03209535721, 1003.25309970443, 
1025.56743956652, 1011.92002817369, 1010.29743022209, 1012.48175793277, 
1009.63063375751, 1003.35694102903, 1006.91036586892, 1008.53691852797, 
1004.39617687043, 1005.34939694712, 1007.38032829588, 1006.2406657999, 
1003.55732294589, 1002.3200249671, 1006.39254974438, 1006.23573445581, 
1003.10850022259, 1013.58992171981, 1005.04464304009, 1005.62233873107
), var_10 = c(994.327042030287, 1000.15918365269, 1003.17401220482, 
1002.41479226363, 1001.17012593697, 1012.75282463779, 999.464067607865, 
1003.33072474503, 993.839707725624, 1003.03797140798, 1004.42881386089, 
1002.81796777502, 1002.07031118448, 992.327926936543, 1002.76956021356, 
999.681970401198, 1004.23210597331, 1001.85997966737, 1000.9722244689, 
1001.93604180609, 1002.11916794344, 994.602579098966, 1000.03472445261, 
995.66066961146, 997.917574584763), var_11 = c(999.225538268699, 
1001.51403741206, 1002.74763442988, 1006.55857216695, 999.637387760292, 
1016.5065564384, 1003.56318544047, 1006.49648576605, 1000.40719170043, 
1005.19870793783, 1005.56965921078, 1002.27122847213, 1004.34660284151, 
996.248419196021, 1002.71639671749, 1001.81478467865, 1003.72063461782, 
1000.14922997608, 1002.47692422786, 1003.71871325602, 1001.8572443969, 
994.892505165028, 1001.97916368443, 998.237282789462, 999.919680379218
), var_12 = c(1009.99385579756, 1003.7899021821, 1006.34418311104, 
1011.89121961563, 1001.04545904874, 1022.13789464831, 1008.53744587416, 
1007.92145847204, 1013.2326207796, 1008.65720626559, 1003.6553384404, 
1005.1228056994, 1007.7451172837, 1002.00057785518, 1005.46564282737, 
1007.33605094724, 1006.79108056397, 1003.23055080249, 1001.16267428815, 
1007.26747194149, 1003.51813473707, 1002.44180972822, 1008.8316595985, 
1002.60112153748, 1005.16871756657), var_13 = c(999.801263745036, 
1003.11042068113, 1000.70169995102, 1006.69246804854, 1001.37744267414, 
1004.70492544978, 996.725751886115, 999.451920807283, 997.963377491494, 
1001.74578985593, 1004.7071611424, 1000.11284080893, 998.968038016249, 
996.628274431963, 1005.00204428575, 1002.89875624369, 1005.10788499684, 
1004.13801289433, 1000.95103389689, 1003.74570635774, 999.0462473717, 
997.461987403548, 999.943757410855, 993.693995026749, 1003.42195795554
), var_14 = c(1002.96437294923, 1003.44844607015, 999.880559826981, 
1007.32640154038, 1000.71689406196, 1006.4489695839, 999.118472788132, 
1000.91418088135, 1002.10232992004, 1002.92045510619, 1003.86468109537, 
997.566194245209, 1001.32843479186, 997.421272961484, 1006.29976121969, 
1002.80516686935, 1003.87077739797, 999.162247485917, 1001.42192692668, 
1003.70559987919, 997.648675071306, 995.38160095025, 1000.70789460245, 
995.349858555166, 1003.99189974754), var_15 = c(1006.28027312932, 
1001.08242973466, 1001.22060069797, 1008.73650967215, 998.66379615346, 
1008.11715753014, 1002.88799699943, 998.644912829098, 1009.53009273459, 
1003.75491412513, 1001.30382513004, 999.123967212071, 1002.01133614154, 
997.859459866021, 1006.9700120191, 1003.15582202707, 1004.70486363208, 
1000.51968370413, 998.613043102328, 1006.00477421965, 999.102913452971, 
999.795880345749, 1003.7550369496, 997.228089565745, 1004.45145073668
)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

**DATASET 2**

```
structure(list(var_1 = c(1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 
16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 30, 44, 46, 49), var_2 = c("soap", 
"soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", 
"soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", 
"soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap"
), var_3 = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B"), var_4 = c(996.004085290553, 1005.03749946898, 998.028313183065, 
993.307008354785, 1003.55106999008, 1001.70676077155, 997.493277888883, 
1001.88777321898, 993.025572998031, 1000.52429967762, 999.738626511572, 
1003.19617639836, 999.618564942695, 997.542557651224, 1001.91803490989, 
994.646255918378, 994.600444797032, 1006.24433066413, 999.931476919632, 
993.378653285675, 1002.02997952225, 996.021480043152, 996.078996748316, 
993.289940301651, 994.302747991299), var_5 = c(1000.62150212342, 
1007.75899775608, 998.076594704249, 994.076210622421, 1001.65779442628, 
1005.31481098188, 1000.14208348451, 1004.52018125654, 998.442630353649, 
1002.00051785325, 1001.30346907199, 1004.36353100771, 999.984147937288, 
1001.01799377569, 1002.16398550184, 993.932968362631, 995.644548584261, 
1003.80236232314, 1000.83558931924, 994.495240005727, 1003.00187233307, 
994.795495894296, 997.986242971177, 995.517416599455, 995.862634914667
), var_6 = c(1012.9554415821, 1016.67103699915, 1002.15365554737, 
1006.86762877786, 1008.45962311068, 1009.97183712754, 1010.63203584184, 
1011.88521795707, 1014.30761724848, 1005.04681800218, 1002.29899409537, 
1007.81908431469, 1003.47474629234, 1006.56231512355, 1006.819669006, 
1001.10301223694, 999.068346627951, 1005.15548250667, 1001.80359068951, 
1000.76931618851, 1008.01071628743, 1003.46633322373, 1007.74933708915, 
1000.62743538132, 1007.14786907481), var_7 = c(992.418094914622, 
997.971380355398, 1002.2292388993, 997.937032776913, 1000.0422658299, 
1003.93467692475, 1000.2377260519, 1000.3181007915, 984.200151469856, 
998.160204449011, 1000.62462329497, 1001.76690658846, 996.826940359061, 
995.607929239509, 999.702054315567, 997.291471462544, 1000.26949897499, 
1001.63525170543, 999.143272890465, 997.785664145926, 1000.12771042363, 
992.741136330753, 997.578584047386, 994.676525112309, 995.763507296891
), var_8 = c(997.18267770374, 1000.16039368502, 1002.7069399281, 
998.62698748611, 998.728473297166, 1008.11964589961, 1004.15235381401, 
1000.78341401868, 990.209681874658, 1000.20800539735, 1001.48137456348, 
1002.84860039832, 999.730997287674, 1000.17928456999, 999.907971391359, 
998.723779888022, 1001.96978732491, 999.984520817739, 999.400843752972, 
999.807509276376, 1001.02554478707, 992.572297236651, 999.654883358304, 
997.283148054673, 997.515534614852), var_9 = c(1009.42367409926, 
1009.07903916629, 1004.91476855238, 1005.86927622259, 1002.71096740085, 
1013.09901927997, 1009.67397418906, 1005.94015305892, 1001.00612108991, 
1003.08031473771, 999.866407799831, 1006.75669517393, 1004.47409706618, 
1006.06169418873, 1004.85729686493, 1004.95764559864, 1004.07498375648, 
1000.95678296744, 999.167788093111, 1002.97245026798, 1002.98791225156, 
999.995403485561, 1008.10285456645, 1001.05106189387, 1005.87476640145
), var_10 = c(997.033470393412, 1001.97377908784, 1002.27932356239, 
1001.37236796086, 999.964771265342, 1005.290878105, 999.649764748948, 
1000.36835347925, 988.307000532414, 999.894390486631, 1000.79036688202, 
1000.48131252765, 998.301279282178, 996.295346692933, 999.88233615018, 
1000.49579177747, 1004.24930021206, 1004.49876374949, 998.117834474685, 
1000.39619941862, 999.202219489554, 992.098413491644, 1000.71379455593, 
995.008386022583, 997.093225761927), var_11 = c(1001.14010250645, 
1003.76051565494, 1003.29833843754, 1000.60539548502, 998.034039799405, 
1009.47863905986, 1002.81836003896, 1000.05837737854, 993.304682798038, 
1001.95912937006, 1001.73555945138, 1001.08565421371, 1001.13778488337, 
1001.11347399164, 999.987444674806, 1001.84877511449, 1006.11884162455, 
1002.26488777145, 997.633160438494, 1002.16160561309, 999.93867109169, 
990.49221922292, 1002.05005047141, 997.057707013846, 998.691024619626
), var_12 = c(1010.6989716872, 1008.52123662618, 1004.94124365003, 
1005.33467168056, 1000.45601490752, 1012.37379951646, 1006.44029646493, 
1003.67962142328, 1001.19234165952, 1003.56217081729, 999.044137362938, 
1004.20070031589, 1003.53005530276, 1006.27767029539, 1004.21138025612, 
1004.92138251507, 1004.88215501513, 1002.2471948666, 997.362509964893, 
1003.85188130527, 1001.3586497828, 999.090746091081, 1006.3336610853, 
999.614422623217, 1005.14162645295), var_13 = c(1000.89599227983, 
1003.83846437952, 998.660833714301, 1005.63873342951, 1001.98775658049, 
1001.0458886613, 999.262970466697, 1002.8340643117, 995.898021564517, 
1001.00885828308, 1003.41865997847, 1001.68471621974, 999.638442866221, 
1000.27642468783, 1001.76823718364, 1001.68068636794, 1008.57093653637, 
1007.14602235806, 999.754190491106, 1000.58595620726, 998.473722265129, 
996.609969985822, 1000.14533441949, 994.614899343371, 1001.56160375018
), var_14 = c(1002.94619035116, 1004.70457675466, 999.59436981446, 
1001.59973104217, 999.988638552344, 1003.79329103591, 1000.54733638917, 
1000.54437978721, 997.9837416027, 1002.47669253217, 1003.99379121188, 
1001.80643385497, 1002.22142205601, 1003.56904822059, 1002.05354063484, 
1002.24420650476, 1008.04385138833, 1003.94854087847, 998.733435450058, 
1001.54527082822, 998.125258605737, 995.45325930152, 1001.06029338143, 
995.67060458657, 1003.38297407426), var_15 = c(1007.68162285336, 
1005.36085942954, 1000.47666761108, 1004.57722295264, 999.452420534917, 
1002.03237948844, 1000.2243126431, 999.475572814555, 1000.35458151391, 
1001.13298849399, 999.017064800029, 1002.67697914555, 1001.82011380148, 
1003.40649787754, 1004.05060374186, 1001.54086695776, 1004.86622757701, 
1002.66173787498, 997.757375273718, 1001.13798685232, 999.410527740961, 
1001.91885824018, 1002.21121622484, 997.33958750622, 1008.18987741896
)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

**DATASET 3**

```
structure(list(var_1 = c(1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 
16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 30, 44, 46, 49), var_2 = c("soap", 
"soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", 
"soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", 
"soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap", "soap"
), var_3 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C"), var_4 = c(988.856158671407, 1000.23888564896, 997.039675082569, 
1001.09291198164, 1002.98988896299, 1005.41677956183, 997.170442654021, 
1008.16418133488, 990.169419475989, 1002.11962397764, 1000.65881048338, 
1000.6255556549, 996.706428965879, 993.887084764435, 1000.5277212491, 
997.595615809563, 992.846778862404, 1000.37249544151, 999.435545324196, 
995.477367164094, 1003.05859761336, 999.47812876303, 995.860251713007, 
995.632372813146, 999.770083493782), var_5 = c(994.468875098246, 
1003.96990710863, 996.401009591011, 1005.87900720863, 1003.10043497883, 
1006.86178446511, 1000.16218228559, 1014.54963756727, 994.616732970479, 
1004.23167123533, 1002.37269462739, 1001.87516303241, 997.778855524445, 
996.483722875524, 1001.1303870722, 998.160790249582, 990.769696036975, 
1000.45401759063, 1002.01859674451, 998.79253832661, 1004.13493084409, 
1000.54459607728, 997.719615789644, 999.380020106129, 1002.62315679074
), var_6 = c(1012.10534266625, 1015.40462298842, 999.9107434841, 
1014.38627383064, 1008.93405130319, 1015.18680921429, 1010.14219845841, 
1020.70520656907, 1007.5072983389, 1010.76932384644, 1007.87875085817, 
1005.48278706243, 1003.35777109534, 1003.47085321062, 1007.33985613752, 
1007.25872117706, 999.112164307972, 1002.29939831067, 1003.07417333636, 
1003.85793371694, 1009.53278894638, 1011.19644538506, 1011.23395633535, 
1007.39260082121, 1013.65590374333), var_7 = c(990.850727928741, 
993.398346143465, 1002.54036572775, 997.364309124077, 1002.08056674659, 
1005.06669915366, 1004.31923128858, 1003.23718800791, 994.268259914595, 
1000.67737011882, 999.619189546307, 1002.68202480584, 999.041146242958, 
993.414424263201, 1000.59471576055, 1000.19683225081, 1000.16517157422, 
997.540443383467, 1001.84917352127, 1001.07658425743, 1004.40588599635, 
998.823414049946, 997.858229406642, 994.87259980467, 998.785952807378
), var_8 = c(994.890815628412, 996.851278420874, 1002.1043798945, 
1005.81171180245, 1002.87987510596, 1007.79412746756, 1009.50695673265, 
1008.01447499455, 999.512821404105, 1004.2013984755, 1000.81528330285, 
1004.35199943309, 1002.11976068962, 997.40997781305, 1001.88805943989, 
1002.594272601, 998.560175268731, 998.135153010693, 1004.4252040573, 
1004.73673205744, 1005.71745745982, 1001.17048429098, 999.360169227143, 
997.384140934815, 1001.00287124848), var_9 = c(1009.51261484649, 
1005.02619159395, 1005.49719893791, 1010.84145164945, 1004.68478802971, 
1016.32418136177, 1014.69013052771, 1012.07680708286, 1012.41952646586, 
1010.56312371765, 1004.28046277054, 1007.64737651417, 1007.08645126073, 
1003.27924738048, 1005.58288092655, 1011.72595267599, 1003.49843659402, 
1001.33918111569, 1003.15289777247, 1007.05337876271, 1007.60523861932, 
1008.12060882554, 1009.93070913311, 1002.02262615479, 1010.11935930848
), var_10 = c(995.608170991922, 998.216388150646, 1001.60211665164, 
999.832076213262, 1001.40362599894, 1008.65746780516, 1005.14963479715, 
1005.69883686071, 995.36726126399, 1001.98356248343, 1002.52938643378, 
1004.44686315697, 1001.88437037401, 992.528325989138, 1000.17011585976, 
1002.59521869899, 1007.04880390672, 998.313461257726, 1000.28328142721, 
1004.36911508867, 1002.78021097217, 996.747503975562, 999.187033093333, 
996.024445680514, 999.229331486915), var_11 = c(999.349990537239, 
1000.25571835554, 1001.09116707486, 1007.06029312947, 1002.72729847885, 
1009.68783611392, 1009.23934223585, 1008.95767573724, 999.644079501528, 
1004.46546567977, 1003.02810334276, 1005.67690071529, 1004.36701185857, 
996.291832791975, 1002.04095164098, 1005.51311465032, 1005.69841082672, 
998.788899712536, 1003.03620977913, 1006.88800630791, 1003.89090518079, 
998.081210763667, 1000.05747905747, 998.094784527214, 1001.67927888372
), var_12 = c(1011.12126521731, 1004.59413830322, 1004.1077131243, 
1010.13326381032, 1002.86650202467, 1016.25544969107, 1012.00856171947, 
1011.06711242009, 1010.68633713312, 1009.10677414828, 1004.92332669674, 
1007.96701055541, 1006.81338213344, 1000.30733607564, 1005.31077105909, 
1010.90426287755, 1007.22349662969, 1001.6706218772, 1001.669317131, 
1007.40312084436, 1004.96827359204, 1003.52588208615, 1007.35889570568, 
1001.24372245315, 1008.83562199571), var_13 = c(996.838989582336, 
1002.27800090558, 1001.75290674649, 1004.7636391085, 1000.97339668679, 
1012.11738595707, 1003.17906097432, 1004.61956745266, 998.954167698171, 
1000.33718227001, 1002.91357065339, 1003.65320446801, 998.795991193962, 
995.260177765719, 1002.5924005443, 1003.26725194424, 1010.94382735439, 
999.908089656425, 996.491714680007, 1003.35958383952, 1000.1980165471, 
996.129597532203, 998.068498757686, 995.940627650744, 1004.06645814493
), var_14 = c(997.870867692911, 1003.02403433836, 1000.66826545719, 
1006.7506344557, 1001.15587576193, 1010.51785193511, 1004.99936090838, 
1004.57223746317, 1000.36408792936, 1000.58925031439, 1001.3954846972, 
1003.55543459632, 1000.99816870794, 997.52989338229, 1004.17893812675, 
1005.94481009989, 1007.51898916194, 999.52752418934, 1000.41259599596, 
1004.95053154685, 1001.27825568282, 997.249111602143, 997.60258568041, 
996.624936012322, 1005.66199164861), var_15 = c(1005.24535230967, 
1002.99896314, 1000.43007709819, 1007.20593389744, 998.711140983915, 
1013.30601537204, 1005.57921718108, 1005.24004334238, 1005.96824937368, 
1001.62293479253, 1002.21921258547, 1004.07313151834, 1000.71338636323, 
997.083115696827, 1004.8346929062, 1006.3003345886, 1007.02302307691, 
1003.2273466626, 998.987599433243, 1004.20438929142, 1002.0228708307, 
1001.34241259142, 1002.11369999794, 996.717876200798, 1008.01351241284
)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I would like merge them by variables:

```
var_1
var_2
```

and keep into the final merged dataset the same order they have of the original one, with the same sequence of all the variables as they are sort in, namely:

```
var_1 
var_2 
var_3 (all three levels column coming from the three different datasets one after the other); 
var_4 = same order as for var_3; 
var_5 = same as above; 
var_5 = same as the three ones above;
```

and so on for all the following variables. My question is how I could do this all in one command by using dplyr %>% operator. However, if you don't know how to figure this out, every method you could suggest will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't get it working in one pipe (maybe someone else does, probably with some weird `purrr` magic), but this one does the trick as well. It's basically first getting the var names, then re-shuffling them into your desired order and then relocate them in the joined df.

```
df_join <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("ID", "GR", "SES"), suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  left_join(df3, by = c("ID", "GR", "SES"), suffix = c("", ".z"))

names_df1 <- (df_join %>%
  select(-ends_with(".y"),
         -ends_with(".z")) %>%
  names())[-c(1:3)]

names_df2 <- df_join %>%
  select(ends_with(".y")) %>%
  names()

names_df3 <- df_join %>%
  select(ends_with(".z")) %>%
  names()

names_all <- data.frame(names_df1, names_df2, names_df3) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(names_all = list(c_across(everything()))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pull(names_all) %>%
  unlist()

df_join <- df_join %>%
  relocate(1:3, all_of(names_all))

str(df_join)

tibble [25 x 42] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ ID                     : chr [1:25] "01" "04" "06" "07" ...
 $ GR                     : chr [1:25] "RP" "RP" "RP" "RP" ...
 $ SES                    : chr [1:25] "V" "V" "V" "V" ...
 $ COND                   : chr [1:25] "NEG-CTR" "NEG-CTR" "NEG-CTR" "NEG-CTR" ...
 $ COND.y                 : chr [1:25] "NEU-NOC" "NEU-NOC" "NEU-NOC" "NEU-NOC" ...
 $ COND.z                 : chr [1:25] "NEG-NOC" "NEG-NOC" "NEG-NOC" "NEG-NOC" ...
 $ P3(400-450).FCz        : num [1:25] -11.631 -0.314 -0.214 -2.831 4.238 ...
 $ P3(400-450).FCz.y      : num [1:25] -4 5.04 -1.97 -6.69 3.55 ...
 $ P3(400-450).FCz.z      : num [1:25] -11.144 0.239 -2.96 1.093 2.99 ...
 $ P3(400-450).Cz         : num [1:25] -5.17 2.23 -1.3 2.19 2.45 ...
 $ P3(400-450).Cz.y       : num [1:25] 0.622 7.759 -1.923 -5.924 1.658 ...
 $ P3(400-450).Cz.z       : num [1:25] -5.53 3.97 -3.6 5.88 3.1 ...
 $ P3(400-450).Pz         : num [1:25] 11.88 15.1 3.14 13.68 7.48 ...
 $ P3(400-450).Pz.y       : num [1:25] 12.96 16.67 2.15 6.87 8.46 ...
 $ P3(400-450).Pz.z       : num [1:25] 12.1053 15.4046 -0.0893 14.3863 8.9341 ...
 $ LPPearly(500-700).FCz  : num [1:25] -11.779 -4.015 4.467 -0.884 1.145 ...
 $ LPPearly(500-700).FCz.y: num [1:25] -7.5819 -2.0286 2.2292 -2.063 0.0423 ...
 $ LPPearly(500-700).FCz.z: num [1:25] -9.15 -6.6 2.54 -2.64 2.08 ...
 $ LPPearly(500-700).Cz   : num [1:25] -5.964 -1.436 3.522 5.499 -0.434 ...
 $ LPPearly(500-700).Cz.y : num [1:25] -2.82 0.16 2.71 -1.37 -1.27 ...
 $ LPPearly(500-700).Cz.z : num [1:25] -5.11 -3.15 2.1 5.81 2.88 ...
 $ LPPearly(500-700).Pz   : num [1:25] 8.24 5.06 7.56 13.03 3.25 ...
 $ LPPearly(500-700).Pz.y : num [1:25] 9.42 9.08 4.91 5.87 2.71 ...
 $ LPPearly(500-700).Pz.z : num [1:25] 9.51 5.03 5.5 10.84 4.68 ...
 $ LPP1(500-1000).FCz     : num [1:25] -5.673 0.159 3.174 2.415 1.17 ...
 $ LPP1(500-1000).FCz.y   : num [1:25] -2.9665 1.9738 2.2793 1.3724 -0.0352 ...
 $ LPP1(500-1000).FCz.z   : num [1:25] -4.392 -1.784 1.602 -0.168 1.404 ...
 $ LPP1(500-1000).Cz      : num [1:25] -0.774 1.514 2.748 6.559 -0.363 ...
 $ LPP1(500-1000).Cz.y    : num [1:25] 1.14 3.761 3.298 0.605 -1.966 ...
 $ LPP1(500-1000).Cz.z    : num [1:25] -0.65 0.256 1.091 7.06 2.727 ...
 $ LPP1(500-1000).Pz      : num [1:25] 9.99 3.79 6.34 11.89 1.05 ...
 $ LPP1(500-1000).Pz.y    : num [1:25] 10.699 8.521 4.941 5.335 0.456 ...
 $ LPP1(500-1000).Pz.z    : num [1:25] 11.12 4.59 4.11 10.13 2.87 ...
 $ LPP2(1000-1500).FCz    : num [1:25] -0.199 3.11 0.702 6.692 1.377 ...
 $ LPP2(1000-1500).FCz.y  : num [1:25] 0.896 3.838 -1.339 5.639 1.988 ...
 $ LPP2(1000-1500).FCz.z  : num [1:25] -3.161 2.278 1.753 4.764 0.973 ...
 $ LPP2(1000-1500).Cz     : num [1:25] 2.964 3.448 -0.119 7.326 0.717 ...
 $ LPP2(1000-1500).Cz.y   : num [1:25] 2.9462 4.7046 -0.4056 1.5997 -0.0114 ...
 $ LPP2(1000-1500).Cz.z   : num [1:25] -2.129 3.024 0.668 6.751 1.156 ...
 $ LPP2(1000-1500).Pz     : num [1:25] 6.28 1.08 1.22 8.74 -1.34 ...
 $ LPP2(1000-1500).Pz.y   : num [1:25] 7.682 5.361 0.477 4.577 -0.548 ...
 $ LPP2(1000-1500).Pz.z   : num [1:25] 5.25 3 0.43 7.21 -1.29 ...
```

---

Another solution could be (assuming that all your three data sets are in the same, correct order) to just create a loop that selects the first three columns, then column 4 from df1, column 4 from df2, column 4 from df3, then the 5th column for each data set, then the 6th and so on.

---

Update based on the comment from TO:

> May you kindly, in case I would like to have not the pointed out
> variables one beside the other one but all in a columun with a single
> name (i.e. the column COND should contain values of COND and below
> COND.y and below again COND.x and the same for the corresponding
> values in other columns) , how the code is supposed to be reshaped?

I'm not 100% sure what solution better fits your purpose, but here are two different groupings/sortings:

A) We bind the data rowwise, so that first row comes from df1, second row from df2 and so on. This still keeps all your other columns.

```
df_join <- df1 %>%
  add_row(df2) %>%
  add_row(df3) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

B) We can pivot_longer so that also the "real" variables are below each other. You need an additional sorting variable based on the variable names column:

```
df_join %>%
  mutate(data_ID = c(rep(1, nrow(df1)),
                     rep(2, nrow(df2)),
                     rep(3, nrow(df3))),
         .before = 1) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(data_ID, ID, GR, SES, COND)) %>%
  group_by(data_ID) %>%
  mutate(vars_sort = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(vars_sort)

# A tibble: 900 x 8
   data_ID ID    GR    SES   COND    name                    value vars_sort
     <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>                   <dbl>     <int>
 1       1 01    RP    V     NEG-CTR P3(400-450).FCz       -11.6           1
 2       2 01    RP    V     NEU-NOC P3(400-450).FCz        -4.00          1
 3       3 01    RP    V     NEG-NOC P3(400-450).FCz       -11.1           1
 4       1 01    RP    V     NEG-CTR P3(400-450).Cz         -5.17          2
 5       2 01    RP    V     NEU-NOC P3(400-450).Cz          0.622         2
 6       3 01    RP    V     NEG-NOC P3(400-450).Cz         -5.53          2
 7       1 01    RP    V     NEG-CTR P3(400-450).Pz         11.9           3
 8       2 01    RP    V     NEU-NOC P3(400-450).Pz         13.0           3
 9       3 01    RP    V     NEG-NOC P3(400-450).Pz         12.1           3
10       1 01    RP    V     NEG-CTR LPPearly(500-700).FCz -11.8           4
# ... with 890 more rows
```

Comment: Great. It is pretty useful. It would good to see the loop as well just for get how it is supposed to work. But if you canoot show, it does not matter. Thanks

Comment: see update above

Comment: Thanks. The first code is exaclty the way I intended to reshape it. I know that it would take time to a deep exaplanation, but if you don't mind I would just need to turn to you a question: when you enter the minus sign ahead c(....) or the function ends_with what does that really refer to in such a way? Pleease jusyt consider my only if ypu can. I'm practilly a beginner in using R language?

Comment: It basically turns the operation into its opposite, so e.g. `ends_with("...")` means you want to select a certain variable if it ends with "...". Putting a minus sign before it means you want to select if it DOESN'T end with "...". Same with `-c`, i.e. `c(1:3)` in this context means I wanted to have the first three elements. Putting the minus sign before it means I wanted to have everything EXCEPT the first three elements.